# Git history. Find commits, included in merge commit

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

I have command: `git log --pretty=format:'* %s' --no-merges --first-parent beta $(git describe --match builds/beta/* --abbrev=0 HEAD)..HEAD`

to find commits between last `builds/beta/..` tag and `HEAD`. But I want to include there commits from merge commits.

For example, I have commit: "Merge branch `feature/request` into `beta`. I want to get commits, included in that merge commit too. It is possible?

Comment: Thanks @OznOg. That should be accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try removing  --first-parent